# Is there an easy way to evaluate String such as "81+23*5-21" in java?

Tags: java, string, double, evaluation

I'm trying to build a android calculator apps. I'll have some String such as `"13+23-3"` or `"40*2+3"`.
Is there a method can directly convert this kind of strings into double (with correct operator precedence)? Or i have to write a method myself?

I'd tried Double.parseDouble() and Double.valueOf() but both failed to convert it.

Comment: Or ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302142/writing-string-evaluation-function?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) class and use [eval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval%28java.lang.String%29) function. I guess there may be a better way, but this will work, though not efficient certainly.

```
ScriptEngineManager m = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine e = m.getEngineByName("js");        
Object result = e.eval("13+23-3");
```